# Get a formula for sum of squares through functional equations

Tags: polynomials, induction, functional-equations, sums-of-squares

Can you get the formula for evaluating the sum of the squares of the first $n$ natural numbers by solving the functional equation $f(x + 1) = f(x) + (x + 1)^2$

Comment: Sure. Substitute a general cubic and equate coefficients.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I'm just from doing that and it works

Comment: But how do you know it's a cubic

Comment: If the leading term is $ax^n$, then it is clear that it will cancel from both sides upon expanding. So what will remain is $bx^{n-1}$, which needs to match the highest power leftover, which is $x^2$ in the $(x+1)^2$.

Comment: I'm beginning to have a lot of respect for you

Comment: And last one, can you then derive Falhauber's formula from this line of reasoning

Comment: If you could it'd be very messy probably.

Comment: I agree. But let me try for $n^4$ and see what happens